# (Javascript) Is it possible the Object.keys() return a list of objects?

Tags: javascript, object

I want acess the keys of a object but those keys are objects too.

```
const caio = new Person("Caio")
const rafael = new Person("Rafael")

const expense = {caio: 10, rafael: 0}

console.log(Object.keys(expense))
#result ['caio', 'rafael']
```

I would want to acess the objects caio/rafael (Person objects). Is it possible?

Comment: "caio" and "rafael" are not objects; they are *variables* (well, constants) whose *values* are objects.

Comment: And the direct answer to the question is no; `Object.keys()` always returns an array of strings, because object property names are always strings.

Comment: Your keys are not objects.  You just happen to have variables which are the same name as those keys.  If those variables are themselves objects on a property then you can reference them by their name.  But that seems like a really round-about approach to... whatever it is you're trying to do.  Which isn't entirely clear.

Comment: you need to think about a better structuring of your data

Comment: Why do you need this? Are the keys of the `expense` object known to you before hand? You could do something like this `Object.keys(expense).map(name=> ({ name, value: expense[name], person: new Person(name) }))` This will have name, expenseValue and the Person object tied together. Or you could pass the expense value to the `Person` constructor

Comment: Thanks all for helping... What I was looking for is something similar to dictionary in Python. Map will be perfect for me. A friend told me that is not a good way to structure my code and give me some tips to refactory too. Thank all again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS objects can only have `string` or `symbol` as keys so that's not possible.

On the other hand, a `Map` can have `object` keys so you may use one instead:

```js
const expenses = new Map();
expenses.set(caio, 10);
expenses.set(raphael, 0);
const personIterator = expenses.keys() // will return an iterator of the keys
Array.from(personIterator) // an array containing the keys
```

Comment: `expenses.keys()` returns an iterator. `Array.from(expenses.keys())` will get you the array of objects

Comment: Thank you Valentin.. I'm trying "translate" some code in Python to Javascript and Map has the same behavior to Dictionary in Python. It works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without `eval`, I don't think you can do it dynamically in a safe way. But you could have a "map" to do this that uses shorthand initialization:

```js
class Person { constructor(name) { this.name = name; } }

const caio = new Person("Caio")
const rafael = new Person("Rafael")

const pplmap = { caio, rafael };

const expense = {caio: 10, rafael: 0}

console.log(Object.keys(expense).map((p) => pplmap[p]));
```